# Prove that if the largest number of lin. indep. vectors in a vector space $V$ is $n$ then any $n$ lin. independent vectors form a basis for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Prove that if the largest number of linearly independent vectors in a
>   vector space $V$ is $n$ then any $n$ linearly independent vectors form a
>   basis for $V$.

My attempt:

"$n$ is the largest number of linearly independent vectors" implies that *any* $n+1$ vectors will be linearly dependent.

Consider arbitrary $n$ linearly independent vectors in vector space $V$, say $\{\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2},\cdots,\mathbf{v}_{n}\}$

Let $\mathbf{v}_{n+1}$ be arbitrary vector in $V$.

Consider following:

$$S = \{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n,\mathbf{v}_{n+1}\}$$

Since $n$ is the largest number of linearly independent vectors, we can conclude that $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n,\mathbf{v}_{n+1}\}$ are linearly dependent. In other words, following linear combination

$$k_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1} + k_{2}\mathbf{v}_{2} + \cdots + k_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n} + k_{n+1}\mathbf{v}_{n+1} = \bf O$$

Holds when at least one scalar $≠ 0$. If there are non-zero scalars, $k_{n+1}$ must be one of them. Because if $k_{n+1}=0$ we will have

$$k_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1} + k_{2}\mathbf{v}_{2} + \cdots + k_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n} + \mathbf{O} = \bf O$$

Which will only hold when *all* the scalars are zero. But we've specified that at least one must be non-zero.

We have

$$k_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1} + k_{2}\mathbf{v}_{2} + \cdots + k_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n} + k_{n+1}\mathbf{v}_{n+1} = \bf O \implies$$

$$k_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1} + k_{2}\mathbf{v}_{2} + \cdots + k_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n}  = -k_{n+1}\mathbf{v}_{n+1} \implies$$

Dividing both sides by $-k_{n+1}$ ($k_{n+1} ≠ 0$)  gives

$$-\frac{k_{1}}{k_{n+1}}\mathbf{v}_{1} + -\frac{k_{2}}{k_{n+1}}\mathbf{v}_{2} + \cdots + -\frac{k_{n}}{k_{n+1}}\mathbf{v}_{n}  = \mathbf{v}_{n+1} $$

We can see that vector $\mathbf{v}_{n+1}$ can be written as linear combination of the vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n$.  Since $\mathbf{v}_{n+1}$ was arbitrary, we conclude that all vectors in $V$ can be written as linear combination of $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n$. Hence they span $V$. We also know that they are linearly independent. Therefore, they form a basis. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!